# Beta Distribution Fitting with constrained location and scale

Tags: mathematical-statistics, fitting, beta-distribution

I'm fitting a set of beta distributions. My data is constrained to live on $[0,1]$, both theoretically and empirically. A typical output of `scipy.stats.beta.fit` looks like:

[image]

which looks passable. However, when looking at parameter values of the fit:

(1.3409948795491502,
 123769.19188741094,
 -0.00016420153241862221,
 4760.2660482183273),

there are very extreme values. The first two values are the $\alpha,\beta$ parameters, followed by location and scale. Note that the empirical and predicted means are 0.0513 and $\mbox{scale}\cdot\alpha/(\alpha+\beta)=0.516$, so the fit itself is reasonable.

I can try constraining `loc=0.0` but this doesn't help much. Ideally i'd like to optimize over the scale parameter, with the requirement that `scale<=1` and `loc>= 0`. Unfortunately I don't see of a way to do this with scipy's methods.

Question 1:
Are there more robust beta fitting methods out there (preferably for python) that can accept such constraints on location and scale?

Question 2:
Maybe I'm just doing something silly here. Should I be filtering outliers in my data better? As an example filtering the top 99-percentile tends to doesn't help much. I've played around with removing some of the 0.0 values and this helps a bit.

Comment: These results are telling you the data don't come from a Beta distribution.  The software can figure that out because there is so much data.  This raises more basic questions: why are you fitting your data, what do you hope that will achieve, and how accurate does the fit even need to be anyway?

Comment: @whuber: That's fair. I'm primarily interested in constructing a prior/posterior for my random variables and the beta-binomial is a nice way of doing this. I'm not going for super accuracy here, just visually, the above is reasonable for the first three quartiles and that's good enough for me.

Comment: @whuber: I should add that my process is binomial, and while I'd love to make it more accurate, there doesn't seem to be many scalable methods to make the posterior calculations efficient. I've looked into Generalized Beta Binomial models, but they tend to be very slow, which is why I'm hoping to get something decent working with just the beta distribution.

Comment: This may or may not be helpful, I found it to be the latter: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit